# Python multiprocessing.Queue is not first in and first out

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am running an image analytical project, where I need to process a video frame by frame. To speed up, I use `multiprocessing` module together with the Queue. The documentation says that Queue is first-in first out, but it does not behave like that in my code snippet. Since I started the queue in the order of frame 1, 2, 3...etc I expect to get the response from `q.get()` in the same frame order, but it doesn't. I get the frame back in the order as they are executed e.g. frame 3, 1, 2...etc.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
def initiateAnalysis(self):
        '''
        Starts the SVD analysis using multiprocessing
        '''
        queue = Queue()
        jobs = list()
        queueList = list()
        collectResponses = list()
        for frame in self.commonFrames:
            p = Process(target=self.collectResponsesFromFrame, args = (frame, queue))
            p.start()
            print(frame, ' process started')
            jobs.append(p)
            queueList.append(queue)
            
        for q in queueList:
            collectResponses.append(q.get())
        
        for p in jobs:
            p.join()
            
        for item in collectResponses:
            print(item['frameNo'])

def collectResponsesFromFrame(self, frame, queue):
    'do something'
     queue.put(frame)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show us where data is written to a Queue, so I don't see how anyone can possibly give you an answer.  You seem to think that the elements of the Queue should have a different order from the frame execution order.  You need to show us why that's surprising.

Comment: I have edited the code on how the response was put into the queue. I expect print(item['frameNo']) to output 1,2,3,4...etc on the same order as they were input. Instead the output was random order.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to change your expectations.  Processes are like independent programs.  Their startup and execution is under control of the operating system, not Python directly.  You can't have parallel execution of Processes and at the same time have everything run in perfect sequence the way you want it; the order of events will always depend on what else the computer is doing.  If you need to guarantee execution order you must explicitly write code to do so, using (for example) the synchronization primitives provided with the multiprocessing package.